# DynamoDB Change Range Key Column

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to modify the Rangekey column after table creation. Such as adding new column/attribute and assigning as RangeKey for the table. Tried searching but cant ble to find any articles about changing the Range or Hash key

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not possible to change the hash key, range key, or indexes after a table is created in DynamoDB. The DynamoDB [`UpdateItem` API Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html) is clear about the fact that indexes cannot be modified. I can't find a reference to anywhere in the docs that explicitly states that the table keys cannot be modified, but at present they cannot be changed.

Note that DynamoDB is schema-less other than the hash and range key, and you can add other attributes to new items with no problems.  Unfortunately, if you need to modify either your hash key or range key, you'll have to make a new table and migrate the data.

**Edit (January 2014)**: DynamoDB now has support for [on the fly global secondary indexes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-update-online-indexing-reserved-capacity-improvements/)

Comment: So, neither the partition key (primary), nor the sort key can be modified?

Comment: @Vadorequest that's right - if you need to modify that you'd need to create a new table and migrate your data.

Comment: Then I guess the safest way is to not use a hash key by default, and add additional indexes when needed. It's not always obvious what should be the hash when creating the table itself, and forcing all request to provide a hash value to retrieve an item can be quite an issue if it was a bad choice.

Answer (score 15):

To change or create an additional sort key, you will need to create a new table and migrate over to it, as both actions cannot be done on existing tables.

DynamoDB streams enable us to migrate tables without any downtime. I've done this to great effective, and the steps I've followed are:

1. Create a new table (let us call this NewTable), with the desired key structure, LSIs, GSIs.
2. Enable DynamoDB Streams on the original table
3. Associate a Lambda to the Stream, which pushes the record into NewTable. (This Lambda should trim off the migration flag in Step 5)
4. [*Optional*] Create a GSI on the original table to speed up scanning items. Ensure this GSI only has attributes: Primary Key, and Migrated (See Step 5).
5. Scan the GSI created in the previous step  (or entire table) and use the following Filter:

   FilterExpression = "attribute_not_exists(Migrated)"

Update each item in the table with a migrate flag (ie: “Migrated”: { “S”: “0” }, which sends it to the DynamoDB Streams (using UpdateItem API, to ensure no data loss occurs).

**NOTE**: You may want to increase write capacity units on the table during the updates.

6. The Lambda will pick up all items, trim off the Migrated flag and push it into NewTable.
7. Once all items have been migrated, repoint the code to the new table
8. Remove original table, and Lambda function once happy all is good.

Following these steps should ensure you have no data loss and no downtime.

I've documented this on my blog, with code to assist:
https://www.abhayachauhan.com/2018/01/dynamodb-changing-table-schema/

Comment: Abhay, the link you provided is not valid anymore.